# C# - Issue with InitializeComponent

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, authentication, initialization

Apologies, I am a very basic user and require some assistance with this slight issue. I am implementing a WinForms library app - connected to a local DB which also has existing records within.

I'm currently coding the login section, which is based on user - User functionality permissions. I have managed to set up an admin user and a default user, which both work on application loading.

The issue is with InitializeComponent(); - The app loads correctly and users have the correct functionality permissions on first use of the app, however, when the user goes back and forth within the application's submenus and reverts back to the main menu, an admin loses some functionality permissions (i.e. an admin user has correct permissions on first use of app, but ends up having the same functions as a normal user when navigating further on the app and reverting back to the main menu, where all the functions are)

I think the issue lies within the second use of MainMenuForm (where there is ': this ("")'

That part is not correctly set - I want the application to always maintain the same user that was logged in with, but its not because of this, which causes the error.

This is what I have so far, it probably needs some changing, but I'm not sure exactly where and how. Help will be greatly appreciated.

```
namespace Library_System_Project
{
    public partial class MainMenuForm : Form
    {
        // You can call this one at runtime.
        public MainMenuForm(string Role)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lblRole.Text = Role;
        }

    // Designer will call this one.
    public MainMenuForm()
        : this ("")
  // Calls the first constructor.
    {
    }
```

---

Relates to the below:

```
private void MainMenuForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (((Form)this).Controls["lblRole"].Text != "jHarrington")
            {
                btnUserMenu.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Anyone can help on this please?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar problem at beginning, I had to define roles / users.

I found simple solution by creating new form which is only for logging purpose, after that depending on assigned role it created new instance of mainform with conditions.
Simply switch between roles, check below :

```
case "eng":

    MainForm MainForm2 = new MainForm();
    ((Control)MainForm2.tabPage1).Enabled = true;
    MainForm2.LoadDataParts();
    MainForm2.DataGridCount();
    ((Control)MainForm2.tabPage2).Enabled = false;
    ((Control)MainForm2.tabPage3).Enabled = false;
    ((Control)MainForm2.tabPage4).Enabled = false;
    ((Control)MainForm2.tabPage5).Enabled = false;
    MainForm2.btnCB_Add.Enabled = false;
    MainForm2.button10.Enabled = false;
    MainForm2.btnCD_Delete.Enabled = false;
    MainForm2.dataGridView5.Visible = false;
    MainForm2.dataGridView7.Visible = false;
    MainForm2.dataGridView1.CellDoubleClick -= new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(MainForm2.DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick);

    MainForm2.Show();
    break;
```